# Finding the expression of a power series.

Tags: calculus, power-series

So I have the infinite sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} nx^{2n}$$

I have found in a previous part that the convergence interval is $(-1,1)$.

I know that the sum should equal

$$\frac {x^2}{{(x^2 +1)}^2}$$

when $|x|\lt1$

But I'm not sure how I can show this from the sum.

Comment: Fairly related: [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall the alternating geometric series:

$$\frac1{1+x}=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}x^n$$

Differentiate both sides and multiply both sides by $-x:$

$$\frac x{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}nx^n$$

Let $x\mapsto x^2$ and we finally get

$$\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n}$$

Answer (score 6):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses pre-calculus tools only.  To that end, we proceed.

Note that $n=\sum_{m=1}^{n} (1)$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} nx^{2n}&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^n(1) (-x^2)^n\\\\
&=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=m}^\infty (-x^2)^n \,\,\,\,\dots\,\,\text{interchange summation order}\\\\
&=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^m}{1+x^2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\dots\,\,\,\text{Sum inner geometric series}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\dots\,\,\text{Sum geometric series}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: First sum is wrong: upper limit should be n.

Comment: @Nick I've edited that typo; not sure how that got in there.  Thank you for catching it. -Mark

Comment: the simpler the better (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you for the vote.  I like seeing solutions that rely on the simplest tools.  And I enjoy seeing overkill too.  ;-))

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} nx^{2n} = x^2 - {}2x^4 + 3x^6 - 4x^8 + 5x^{10} - \cdots
\end{align}
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 n=1 & & n=2 & & n=3 & & n=4 & & n=5 & & \cdots \\[10pt] \hline
x^2 & + & (-x^4) & + & x^6 & + & (-x^8) & + & x^{10} & + & \cdots \\[10pt]
& & (-x^4) & + & x^6 & + & (-x^8) & + & x^{10} & +  & \cdots \\[10pt]
& & & & x^6 & + & (-x^8) & + & x^{10} & + & \cdots \\[10pt]
& & & & & & (-x^8) & + & x^{10} & + & \cdots \\[10pt]
& & & & & & & & x^{10} & + & \cdots \\[10pt]
& & & & & & & & & & \cdots
\end{array}
$$
First find the sum of each row separately. That's easy because each one is a geometric series.

Then find the sum of all those resulting sums. That also easy because that is also a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $n$ as binomial coefficient, then "negate the upper index" $\binom nk=(-1)^k\binom{k-n-1}k$ for $k=n-1$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} nx^{2n}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \binom n{n-1}(x^2)^n
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom {-2}{n-1}(x^2)^n\\
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom {-2}m(x^2)^{m+1}
=x^2(1+x^2)^{-2},
$$
the final step using Newton's (generalised) binomial formula for exponent $-2$.

This may look a bit *ad hoc*, but in fact once you understand the mechanism it allows you to do general summations on $n$ of expressions of the form "polynomial in$~n$ times an $n$-th power", by rewriting the polynomial as a combination of terms $\binom{-k}n$ for negative integers $-k$ (the example has $k=2$). In the example the alternating sign conveniently combined with the one coming from negation of the upper index, but even if it had not been there, an alternating sign is just a special case of an $n$-th power, so if necessary it could be combined with the given $n$-th power.